# Get custom taxonomies from shortcode attribute

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm making a shortcode that filters the custom taxonomies in a page.
I have it working for 90% but i can't transform the attributes from the shortcode into an array that works. I get all taxonomies from the get_taxonomies() function but i want the taxonomies from my shortcode attributes.

So i tried the get_taxonomies() function and it ouputs this and worked:

```php
Array ( [opleiding_niveaus] => opleiding_niveaus [provincies] => provincies [portfolio_category] => portfolio_category [portfolio_field] => portfolio_field [testimonial_category] => testimonial_category [portfolio_tag] => portfolio_tag )
```

What i have now is this instead of get_taxonomies():

```php
$atts = shortcode_atts(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'nothing',
    ), $atts);
    $ShortcodeAtts= esc_attr($atts['taxonomy']);
    $taxonomies = explode(',', $ShortcodeAtts);
```

and ouputs this:

```
Array ( [0] => provincies [1] => opleiding_niveaus )
```

My loop looks like this:

```
if  ($taxonomies) {
            foreach ($taxonomies  as $taxonomy ) {
                echo '<h4>'. $taxonomy. '</h4>';
                $terms = get_terms(array(
                    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                    'hide_empty' => false,
                ));
                $count = count($terms);
                if ( $count > 0 ){
                    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                        $termlinks= get_term_link($term,$taxonomy);
                        ?> <a href="<?php echo $termlinks; ?>">
                        <?php echo "<div style='display: block'><input type='checkbox' id='".$term->name."'" . $term->name . "/><label for='".$term->name."'>"; echo $term->name?></label></div><?php
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

And the problem with my code is that the shortcode atts array is not well formatted. and gives an error when looping what the get_taxonomies() function not did.

[image]

so what i have looks like this now.
the first taxonomy works, but the second will not work

my shortcode looks like this: `[filter taxonomy="provincies, opleiding_niveaus"]`

full code:

```php
<?php
    add_action('init', 'loadonInit');

    function loadonInit() {
         add_shortcode('filter', 'filter');
    }

    function filter($atts) {

        $args = array('public' => true, '_builtin' => false);
        $atts=shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'nothing',
        ), $atts);
        $ShortcodeAtts= esc_attr($atts['taxonomy']);
        $taxonomies = explode(',', $ShortcodeAtts); 
        // $output = 'names';
        // $operator = 'and';
        // $taxonomies = get_taxonomies($args,$output,$operator); 
        print_r($ShortcodeAttsArray);
        if  ($taxonomies) {
            foreach ($taxonomies  as $taxonomy ) {
                echo '<h4>'. $taxonomy. '</h4>';
                $terms = get_terms(array(
                    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                    'hide_empty' => false,
                ));
                $count = count($terms);
                if ( $count > 0 ){
                    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                        $termlinks= get_term_link($term,$taxonomy);
                        ?> <a href="<?php echo $termlinks; ?>">
                        <?php echo "<div style='display: block'><input type='checkbox' id='".$term->name."'" . $term->name . "/><label for='".$term->name."'>"; echo $term->name?></label></div><?php
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: Could you put it the full shortcode function? and if possible which error message returned

Comment: I added the full shortcode function

Comment: I solved the problem in 2 minutes now :( . I worked on it for 2 days. But i need to fix still one thing. the problem was in the shortcode. i added a space between the comma and the taxonomy, But don't want that to be a problem. You have a solution for that?

Comment: yes I figured that was it, but I put an answer there for you, if you solve your problem please choose as the accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that moving to shortcode is coming up with space so to solve this before exploding we will remove the spaces from the string

add_action('init', 'loadonInit');

```
function loadonInit() {
     add_shortcode('filter', 'filter');
}

function filter($atts) {

    $args = array('public' => true, '_builtin' => false);
    $atts=shortcode_atts(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'nothing',
    ), $atts);

    $ShortcodeAtts= esc_attr($atts['taxonomy']);
    //removing spaces here
    $ShortcodeAtts = str_replace(" ", "", $ShortcodeAtts );
    $taxonomies = explode(',', $ShortcodeAtts); 

    $output = 'names';
    $operator = 'and';
    $taxonomies = get_taxonomies($args,$output,$operator); 

    if  ($taxonomies) {
        foreach ($taxonomies  as $taxonomy ) {
            echo '<h4>'. $taxonomy. '</h4>';
            $terms = get_terms(array(
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                'hide_empty' => false,
            ));
            $count = count($terms);
            if ( $count > 0 ){
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                    $termlinks= get_term_link($term,$taxonomy);
                    ?> <a href="<?php echo $termlinks; ?>">
                    <?php echo "<div style='display: block'><input type='checkbox' id='".$term->name."'" . $term->name . "/><label for='".$term->name."'>"; echo $term->name?></label></div><?php
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```